# In C language why my selection-sort code doesn't work

Tags: c, sorting, select, selection-sort

I wrote a selection-sort algorithm but didn't work. I cannot find my wrong. Anyone can help me ?

#include <stdio.h>

```
int main () {
    
    int array[100],i,j,position,size,swap;
    
    printf("Enter number of integers\n");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    printf("Enter %d integers\n",size);
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }
    
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        position=i;
            for(j=i;j<size;j++){
                if(array[position]>array[j]){
                    position=j;
                    
                }
                if(position!=i){
                    swap=array[i];
                    array[i]=array[position];
                    array[position]=swap;
                }
            }   
    }
    printf("Sorted list in ascending order\n");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        printf("%d\n",array[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a technical diagnostic. You need to dig a little deeper and explain what it does that's not desirable, and/or what it should do. **Have you stepped through in a debugger**?

Comment: Move the swap part to after the inner loop.

Comment: sorry okay im editing

Comment: Post input used.  Output seen.  Output expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selection sort algorithm sorts an array by repeatedly finding the minimum element (considering ascending order) from the unsorted part and putting it at the beginning.

So the swap needs to happen after you have found the correct position i.e. happening after your for loop is over. So if you switch the if block after the j loop ends, the code should work.

```
for(i=0;i<size;i++){
position=i;
    for(j=i;j<size;j++){
        if(array[position]>array[j]){
            position=j;
        }
    }  
    if(position!=i){
            swap=array[i];
            array[i]=array[position];
            array[position]=swap;
        }
}
```

Comment: Oww i get it man thank you very much. I'm thinking about 2 hours. Thank you a lot